# combinations of cancelling pairs

Tags: combinatorics

I have variables $x_1, x_2, ..., x_s$

I have $\binom{x}{2}$ pairs + $s$ single terms...

I need the number of valid sequences of pairs, such that there are the same number of $x_i$ for all {i in the sequence} such that each $x_i$ appears once as the first term and once as the second term, except for one single term.
Example for $s = 4$:

$x_1$

$(x_1 x_2), (x_2) $ `(the x2 in the second term "cancels" the $x_2$ in the first)`

$(x_1 x_3), (x_3) $

$(x_1 x_4), (x_4) $

$(x_1 x_2), (x_2 x_3), (x_3) $ `(the middle term "cancels" the $x_2$ from the first term, the $x_3$ in the third term cancels the $x_3$ in the second term)`

$(x_1 x_2), (x_2 x_4), (x_4) $

$(x_1 x_3), (x_3 x_2), (x_2) $

$(x_1 x_3), (x_3 x_4), (x_4) $

$(x_1 x_4), (x_4 x_2), (x_2) $

$(x_1 x_4), (x_4 x_3), (x_3) $

$(x_1 x_2), (x_2 x_3), (x_3 x_4), (x_4) $

$(x_1 x_2), (x_2 x_4), (x_4 x_3), (x_3) $

$(x_1 x_3)$, $(x_3 x_2)$, ... etc

= 1 + 3 + 6 + 6 = 16 combinations

how do we express this in terms of s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequences mentioned above can be simplified to the following:

$x_1$

$x_2$$x_2$

$x_3$$x_3$

$x_4$$x_4$

$x_2$$x_2$$x_3$$x_3$

$x_3$$x_3$$x_2$$x_2$

$...$

$x_2$$x_2$$x_3$$x_3$$x_4$$x_4$

$x_2$$x_2$$x_4$$x_4$$x_3$$x_3$

$x_3$$x_3$$x_2$$x_2$$x_4$$x_4$

$x_3$$x_3$$x_4$$x_4$$x_2$$x_2$

$x_4$$x_4$$x_3$$x_3$$x_2$$x_2$

$x_4$$x_4$$x_2$$x_2$$x_3$$x_3$

The number of sequences possible = $\binom{4-1}{0} +1! \binom{4-1}{1}+ 2! \binom{4-1}{2}+3! \binom{4-1}{3}$

For the general $s$ terms, number of ways = $\sum_{k=0}^{s-1} k!\binom{s-1}{k}$

Unfortunately, there is no "nice" closed form for the summation.

Comment: when you say "simplifies to", how is that simplified? I see your last and 4th-to-last elements appear identical

Comment: also with (n choose k) = n!/(k!(n-k)!) could simplify the summation element to (s-1)!/(s-1-k)!... if that's considered to be a simplification

Comment: Sorry I'd mistyped the last two elements. When u consider the sequences, each of them essentially an arrangement  of some subset of $x_2$ to $x_s$ . Yes you are right with that simplification but we can't express it in a form without the summation.